# Cursor and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System services not available to Activities before onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905587/system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate)

I am trying to return the values of a database to a listview but I am getting an error. I am using a cursor to get the data from a table and a SimpleCursorAdapter to read the cursor. This is the method that does this:

```
public void getData(){
        String[] columns = new String[] {ModuleDB.KEY_ROWID, 
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODCODE,
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODNAME,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LECPRAC,
                ModuleDB.KEY_DAYS,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMESTART,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMEEND,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LOCATION,
                ModuleDB.KEY_INFO};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.modcode_entry,
                             R.id.modname_entry,
                             R.id.modlecprac_entry,
                             R.id.modday_entry,
                             R.id.modtimestart_entry,
                             R.id.modtimeend_entry,
                             R.id.modlocation_entry,
                             R.id.modaddinfo_entry};

        Cursor curs = myDatabase.query(ModuleDB.DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (curs != null)
            curs.moveToFirst();

        SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ModuleDataSource.this, R.layout.list_entry, curs, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(dataSource);

        // Make sure to close the cursor
        curs.close();
        }
```

This method is causing the exception: `"System Services not available to activites before onCreate()"`

Can anyone help me with this? I can't find any good tutorials for cursors and cursoradapters and I really am completely lost

EDIT:

This might help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ModuleDataSource dbinfo = new ModuleDataSource(this);
        dbinfo.open();
        dbinfo.getData();
        dbinfo.close();
    }
```

**ModuleDataSource.java**

```
public class ModuleDataSource extends ListActivity{

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private ModuleDB myhelper;

    public ModuleDataSource(Context context){
        myhelper = new ModuleDB(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException { //Open the database for writing
        myDatabase = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){ //Close the database
        myhelper.close();
    }

    public void getData(){
        String[] columns = new String[] {ModuleDB.KEY_ROWID, 
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODCODE,
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODNAME,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LECPRAC,
                ModuleDB.KEY_DAYS,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMESTART,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMEEND,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LOCATION,
                ModuleDB.KEY_INFO};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.modcode_entry,
                             R.id.modname_entry,
                             R.id.modlecprac_entry,
                             R.id.modday_entry,
                             R.id.modtimestart_entry,
                             R.id.modtimeend_entry,
                             R.id.modlocation_entry,
                             R.id.modaddinfo_entry};

        Cursor curs = myDatabase.query(ModuleDB.DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(curs);

        if (curs != null)
            curs.moveToFirst();

        SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ModuleDataSource.this, R.layout.list_entry, curs, columns, to);
        setListAdapter(dataSource);

        }
}
```

EDIT2: Logcat

```
11-06 23:24:07.885: D/AndroidRuntime(887): Shutting down VM
11-06 23:24:07.885: W/dalvikvm(887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adoherty.assignment3/com.adoherty.assignment3.MainActivity}: 
                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:49)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:84)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.adoherty.assignment3.ModuleDataSource.getData(ModuleDataSource.java:74)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.adoherty.assignment3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-06 23:24:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905587/system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate

Comment: What happens when you move the call to `getData()` into `onCreate()`?

Comment: You cannot do the following... **ModuleDataSource dbinfo = new ModuleDataSource(this);** - your `ModuleDataSource` extends `ListActivity` and you cannot create an instance of any type of `Activity` by using `new`. Also you must never try to call methods or access fields belonging to an `Activity` from anywhere other than inside that `Activity` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModuleDataSource extends ListActivity`.. you are creating an instance of that within your Activity.. You cannot instantiate an activity as an object like that

Your ListActivity is likely trying to make some system call that it normally makes in the background automatically for you. Since you are trying to instantiate a ListActivity as an object, the normal Activity process is not happening...

You should move what you have in the ListActivity into your main activity and make your main activity the ListActivity

Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private ModuleDB myhelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myhelper = new ModuleDB(this);
        open();
        getData();
        close();
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException { //Open the database for writing
        myDatabase = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){ //Close the database
        myhelper.close();
    }

    public void getData(){
        String[] columns = new String[] {ModuleDB.KEY_ROWID, 
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODCODE,
                ModuleDB.KEY_MODNAME,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LECPRAC,
                ModuleDB.KEY_DAYS,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMESTART,
                ModuleDB.KEY_TIMEEND,
                ModuleDB.KEY_LOCATION,
                ModuleDB.KEY_INFO};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.modcode_entry,
                             R.id.modname_entry,
                             R.id.modlecprac_entry,
                             R.id.modday_entry,
                             R.id.modtimestart_entry,
                             R.id.modtimeend_entry,
                             R.id.modlocation_entry,
                             R.id.modaddinfo_entry};

        Cursor curs = myDatabase.query(ModuleDB.DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(curs);

        SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ModuleDataSource.this, R.layout.list_entry, curs, columns, to);
        setListAdapter(dataSource);

        }
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks so much. I understand what you mean now I wasn't seeing that error. Just one small thing: when declaring `myhelper = newModuleDB(context)` what exactly do I do with the context since I am no longer declaring it in the constructor?

Comment: replace "context" with "this" .. i changed my answer to reflect that.. sorry.. small oversight

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something in your Activity constructor, that should be done in onCreate() instead.

It's probably the same issue as this one: [System services not available to Activities before onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905587/system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added more code that might shed more light on the error

Comment: Now, seeing your code snippets, I vote for dymmeh's answer.